# верстка iphone отличная от других

Tags: xcode, constraints

Я делаю верстку через constraint. Я хочу отображать вьюшку на устройствах с габаритами wC hR одним размером, на устройствах wR hR другим размером, как на изображении. Предположим только для iphone 5 (wC hR) я хочу задать совершенно другие параметры. Как сделать это через код я знаю, но хотелось бы через констрейнты в сториборде.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]